# Performance impact of Allow filtering on same partition query in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
topic text
country text,
bookmarked text,
id uuid,
PRIMARY KEY (topic,id)
);
```

First query on single partition with allow filtering.

```
select * from posts where topic='cassandra' allow filtering;
```

Second query on single partition without allow filtering.

```
select * from posts where topic='cassandra';
```

My question is what is performance difference between first query and second query? Will first query(with allow filtering) get result from all partition before filtering though we have requested from single partition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow filtering will allow you to run queries without specifying partition key. But if you using one, it will use only specific partition.

In this specific example you should see no difference.

Ran both queries on my test table with tracing on, got single partition in both execution plans:

```
 Executing single-partition query on table_name
```

Comment: I have checked tracing logs and thought that it won't create any performance impact, but just wanted to confirm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `ALLOW FILTERING` when you are querying with a partition key. So for the two queries you mentioned there will be no performance difference.

For Cassandra version 3.0 and up, `ALLOW FILTERING` can be used to query with any fields other than partition key. For example, you can run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts where country='Bangladesh';
```

And for Cassandra version below 3.0, `ALLOW FILTERING` can be used on only primary key.
Although it is not wise to query using `ALLOW FILTERING`.
Because, the only way Cassandra can execute this query is by retrieving all the rows from the table `posts` and then by filtering out the ones which do not have the requested value for the `country` column.
So you should use`ALLOW FILTERING` at you own risk.

Comment: That's true that I don't require Allow Filtering. But just wanted to know performance impact if we give that parameter.